# GLfloat Dynamic Array Declaration

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having some problems dynamically declaring a GLfloat array in Objective-C. Here is the c
ode i'm using:

```
GLfloat *m_bindPositions;

@implementation

int nVerts           = [self m_countVertices];
m_bindPositions      = (GLfloat*)malloc((nVerts * 3) * sizeof(GLfloat));
```

nVerts in this example equals 6704.

if I was to run sizeof(m_bindPositions) it should return 80448.

It currently returns 4.This makes me believe there is an error with the allocation of the

memory and I am not entirely sure why. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` in this case is returning the size of the pointer, not the data pointed at by it.

However, the compiler is what handles sizeof, and it will not dynamically return values based on malloc, so you cannot double-check an allocation like that using `sizeof` (or anything else, other than `malloc_size()`, which will return a number equal to or greater than the allocation, representing the allocation block size.

Comment: You beat me by one second :-)